# jsf2 facesmessage for spring-security badcredentials

Tags: exception, jsf-2, spring-security, message

I use a facelets login form for Spring Security:

```
<h:messages globalOnly="true" layout="table" />
<h:form id="formLogin" prependId="false">
        <h:outputLabel for="j_username" value="Usuario:" />
        <h:inputText id="j_username" value="#{autenticacionController.administrador.login}" />
        <h:outputLabel for="j_password" value="Contraseña:" />
        <h:inputSecret id="j_password" value="#{autenticacionController.administrador.password}" />
        <h:commandButton value="Entrar" action="#{autenticacionController.loginAction}" />
        <h:commandButton value="Cancelar" immediate="true" action="#{autenticacionController.cancelarAction}" />
</h:form>`
```

The loginAction method forwards the request with this:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().dispatch("/j_spring_security_check")
```

It works fine, but how can I show a facesmessage in my h:messages tag if the BadCredentials exception is thrown by Spring Security?

I know it can be done with a phase listener, but I don't like that way (dealing with exceptions in listeners).

I'm trying another way, configuring Spring Security like this:

```
authentication-failure-url="/faces/paginas/autenticacion/login.xhtml?error=1
```

And then in the login page, catch the GET param "error". But how can I show the facesmessage in this way?

Another way I tried was to override the messages properties file of Spring Security (overriding the message for the key "badcredentials"), but it didn't work neither (I didn't know how to show the message).

Anyone know how to do it?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *And then in the login page, catch the GET param "error". But how can I show the facesmessage in this way?*

This way:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="error" validator="#{auth.checkErrors}" />
</f:metadata>
<h:messages />
```

with

```
public void checkErrors(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    if ("1".equals(value)) {
        throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("Invalid credentials"));
    }
}
```

or maybe so:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="error" value="#{auth.error}" />
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{auth.checkErrors}" />
</f:metadata>
<h:messages />
```

with

```
private int error;

public void checkErrors() {
    if (error == 1) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Invalid credentials"));
    }
}
```

Either way, this feels pretty hacky :)

Comment: I don't think it's hacky. I prefer it better than the phase listener way. However, I would prefer overiding the messages property file from Spfing Security, but i don't know how to do it. I tried it but didn't work.

Comment: With hacky I mean more, the error page is bookmarkable and manipulatable which can end up in possible enduser confusion.

Comment: You are right, thank you. By the way, do you know how to do it using the messages properties file from Spring Security? I mean overriding the message for "badCredentials" in it, and show a facesmesage. I saw http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/display-custom-error-message-in-spring-security/ but I think it is for using Spring in the presentation level, not JSF.

Comment: Me neither, just wondering if you knew how to display a facesmessage overriding the messages file from Spring Security. I'm in a doubt about how to show the bad credentials message...I don't like doint it with a phase listener (as it would be called for every rendered page, not just the login page), and the GET parameter way is hacky (as you said). I think it cannot be done neither from a managed bean method (like PostConstruct), because at that time, Spring Security hasn't put the BadCredentials Exception object in the HttpSession. I'm really messed, I think I will use the GET parameter.

Comment: You could also just go for a non-facesmessage way in the view. Something like `<c:if test="#{not empty sessionScope['some.spring.specific.message.key']}">Error: #{sessionScope['some.spring.specific.message.key']}</c:if>`.

Comment: Yes, I've read about that too, I would get rid both of GET parameter and pahse listener. I think I will do that way, but rendering an h:outputText with the message only if the session scope has the key of the exception thrown by Spring Security. Thank you very much and happy new year, or maybe happy "end of the world" as Mayas say :)

Comment: In the EL expression of sessionScope, if the key is not a string constant, but is also a EL expression... how could I write it? Is it possible? I tried "#{not empty sessionScope[#{WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION}]}" but it says syntax error.

Comment: Remove the nested `#{}`. You can't nest EL expressions. Just write whole EL expression inside single `#{}`.

Comment: Ok, I've already done it. Sorry, I didn't knew that. I decided to register here at stackoverflow cause I used to look at it a lot, as it is a very good site. I was began learning JSF one year ago, and I saw you are good at it.